# C# Read every second word from txt file

Tags: c#

I had to:

1. Create a console based application that reads the contents of the file Test.txt
2. The program should then process the information contained within the file and print every second word in the file to the console

So I did the first part(1):

```
namespace kappa
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.txt");

            System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of test.txt = {0}", text);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea how to perform task no.2 ? (display every second word from my test.txt file)

Im just starting my adventure with c# and any help wud be greatly apriciated
Thanks

Comment: Put in a task schedule or use `Thread.Sleep` in a `while(true)` condition?

Comment: 1) Ever heard of indentation? 2) Combine `File.ReadLines`, `string.Split`, `SelectMany` and `index % 2 == 0`.

Comment: I guess the intention of such adventures is to take your own steps towards the goal

Comment: Is this your school assignment ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want to believe that spaces separate words in your text file. You can do it like so:

```
text.Split(' ')[1]
```

If there are many lines in your text file, you can loop through each line and get the second word like this and you also check if the words on each line are greater than one after the split to avoid **System.IndexOutOfRangeException** exception:

```
        foreach(var line in System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\test.txt"))
        {
            if(line.Split(' ').Count() > 1)
            secondWord = line.Split(' ')[1];
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I stucked on this one , rly appreciate your help. All the best ! Ps it's not school task but I just started my IT path so sometimes I just need advice and a bit of help!:)

Comment: Oluwafemi, oki so i finally got a chance to work on that but it didnt work as expected as all what it does is displaying only second word after space in my TEST.TXT file and what i needed it to display is : Second word, Fourth word,Sixth word,Eight word and so on ... Any suggestions? (In a mentioned test.txt file there is just one line with muliple words separated by spaces so no multiple lines of text just so we clear)

Comment: Change the index value i.e [1] to [2] to get the third word and increment to get the next